# I created a XML code as following

Tags: xml

I have written a xml code for the first time which is representing two songs on a cd, where title is a sibling of artist,song is a child of cd, cd is the root element, song is the parent of the artist and song has an attribute called rating that contains a number between 1 and 10. Please let me know is this correct or not if some thing is wrong please correct me. Thanks....

```
<?xml version="1.0?>
<cd>
 <song1 rating ="8">
  <artist>MJ</artist>
  <title>Pop</title>
 <song1/>
 <song2 rating = "9">
  <artist>JL</artist>
  <title>Love</title>
<song2/>
</cd>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a valid xml. You hade quite a few errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cd>
 <song track="1" rating="8">
  <artist>MJ</artist>
  <title>Pop</title>
 </song>
 <song track="2" rating="9">
  <artist>JL</artist>
  <title>Love</title>
</song>
</cd>
```

Here is a online validator: http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: You can press the up arrow, if you like what I did.

Comment: I  have already accepted yr answer and clicked the sign under arrows

Comment: But for up arrow i require 15 reputation which I don't have as I am a new user